# Adding class cotaining std::thread to a vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

Class declaration:

```
class cA{
private:
  std::thread t;
public:
  cA()=default;
};
```

Somehere in another source file:

```
cA *a = new cA();
std::vector<cA> v;
v.push_back(*a);
```

This results in the following error at compile time:

```
C2280: cA::cA(const cA &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

I think it might have something to do with the fact that `std::thread` is missing a copy constructor and that the vector tries to make a copy of the `cA` object. Would anyone be willing to explain?

Comment: (1) Threads are not copyable, and (2) these three lines `cA *a = new cA();
; std::vector<cA> v; v.push_back(*a);` hint rather strongly that you need to brush up your understanding of C++ pointers rather sooner than later. Are you coming from Java background? This is a typical error made by Java refugees.

Comment: would you elaborate a bit further what's wrong with (2) ? I mean this is just a sample code I wrote in here but looking at your reaction I got curious. I mean regarding pointers, I thought I got them pretty well ( i'm from the Reverse Engi field;P)

Comment: Just about everything is wrong with it. This is not how you populate a vector of objects in C++. I repeat my question, are you coming from Java background?

Comment: @Rafal Compare your code with `cA a; v.push_back(a);`, or even `v.push_back(cA());`, or `v.emplace_back();`. There's *zero* reason for dynamic allocation of a `cA` object in your code.

Comment: the sample was just to ilustrate my problem, but thank you for your comment:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::thread` is not copyable, so the compiler can not generate a default copy constructor because it doesn't know what to do with the uncopyable type in the class.  What would it put in the `std::thread` variable in the new copy?

Because it cannot generate the copy constructor, it is deleted, the same as if you had said

```
cA(const cA &) = delete;
```

in your class definition.

Here are the rules for when it can and cannot create an implicit copy constructor:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor

The line relevant to your situation is:

> `T` has non-static data members that cannot be copied (have deleted, inaccessible, or ambiguous copy constructors);

Also, as a comment on your question points out, your actual code, even if it did compile, isn't good.  It will leak a `cA` object.  The correct code here (fixed per comment):

```
v.emplace_back();  // since the cA constructor takes no parameters
```

or

```
v.push_back(cA());
```

Neither of these require `cA` to be copyable because its *move* constructor is used.

Comment: I just wouldn't agree with putting so much pressure onto the pointer/memory leak in this discussion. My question was just related to the error and my suspected reason which was the lack of a copy constructor. In my real case there *is* a need for a dynamic allocation of memory and there is a parametrised constructor, all of which are irrelevant here I suppose. One needs to delete v, and there wouldn't be any leak.

Comment: @Rafal that's why it's just an "also" section.  But maybe someone else coming looking for this question won't know that it's not ok.  Remember, stack overflow answers aren't just for the person asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
v.push_back(std::move(*a));
```